# How to update the twitter share button URL with dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, twitter, pushstate

I initialize the tweet button at the beginning of my app, after user interaction the current window's location is updated using HTML5 pushState, but the twitter button is still sharing the previous URL from when it was initialized.

How do I update the URL that twitter uses?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish basically the same thing. I tried updating the `data-url` attribute dynamically with this: `$('.twitter-share-button').attr("data-url", "http://mynewlink");` but the twitter javascript has already run and this doesn't work. Help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured this out. Here's how to make this work.

The general idea is:

1. In your HTML set the `class` of your `<a>` for the twitter share button to be something other than `.twitter-share-button`.  Also give the `<a>` a `style="display:none;"`.
2. In your HTML, where you want the twitter share button to appear, create a `<div>` (or `<span>`) with a unique `id`.
3. In your jQuery, when you want to set the data for the twitter share button you will:

   - 'clone()`the hidden, mis-named,`` tag from step #1
   - On this clone, set the `data-url` etc... attributes as you'd like
   - Remove the `style` attribute from the clone (unhide it)
   - Change the `class` of the clone to `twitter-share-button`
4. `append()` this clone to your `<div>` from step 2.
5. Use `$.getScript()` to load and run Twitter's Javascript.  This will convert your cloned `<a>` into an `<iframe>` with all the right goop.

Here's my HTML (in Jade):

```
  a.twitter-share-button-template(style="display:none;", href='https://twitter.com/share=', data-lang='en',
      data-url='http://urlthatwillbe_dynamically_replaced',
      data-via='ckindel', data-text='Check this out!',
      data-counturl='http://counturlthatwillbe_dynamically_replaced') Share with Twitter
    #twitter-share-button-div
```

Then in your client-side .js:

```
// the twitter share button does not natively support being dynamically
// updated after the page loads. We want to give it a unique (social_id)
// link whenver this modal is shown. We engage in some jQuery fun here to 
// clone a 'hidden' twitter share button and then force the Twitter
// Javascript to load.

// remove any previous clone
$('#twitter-share-button-div').empty()

// create a clone of the twitter share button template
var clone = $('.twitter-share-button-template').clone()

// fix up our clone
clone.removeAttr("style"); // unhide the clone
clone.attr("data-url", someDynamicUrl); 
clone.attr("data-counturl", someDynamicCountUrl);
clone.attr("class", "twitter-share-button"); 

// copy cloned button into div that we can clear later
$('#twitter-share-button-div').append(clone);

// reload twitter scripts to force them to run, converting a to iframe
$.getScript("http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
```

I got the main clues for this solution from here:
http://tumblr.christophercamps.com/post/4072517874/dynamic-tweet-button-text-using-jquery

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up not using twitters widgets.js script and rolling my own styled twitter anchor tag passing the url as a parameter to the href of the link. This way I have better control over how its styled and positioned.

Comment: This is not working anymore. The iframe src still has reference to the onload url. All other attributes change except for the iframe's src. Not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 15):

I had success using the new Twitter feature that reloads the share url.

```
function updateTwitterValues(share_url, title) {
// clear out the <a> tag that's currently there...probably don't really need this since you're replacing whatever is in there already.
  $(container_div_name).html('&nbsp;'); 
  $(container_div_name).html('<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="' + share_url +'" data-size="large" data-text="' + title + '" data-count="none">Tweet</a>');
twttr.widgets.load();
}
```

My initial HTML just has a container for the share link, like this:

```
<div id="twitter-share-section"></div>
```

Any time I get new data from an ajax call I just call updateTwitterValues() and pass along the new info. More info here https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5642

Answer (score 4):

```
twttr.widgets.load();
```

From [Twitter's Dev Docs](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/initialization).

Comment: Noticed just after answering that this info is contained in another answer. I didn't spot it myself, and found the answer via a Google Search. If I missed the info in the other answer, then others might too - thus I'll leave this here.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
 The tweet button:
 <span id='tweet-span'> 
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" id='tweet' 
           class="twitter-share-button" 
           data-lang="en" 
           data-count='none'>Tweet</a>
 <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</span>

<div>
  <input type="button" onclick="tweetSetup('http://www.google.com','MyGoogle')" value="TestTwitter" />
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function tweetSetup(dynamicurl,dynamictext) {
    $(".twitter-share-button").remove();
    var tweet = $('<a>')
        .attr('href', "https://twitter.com/share")
        .attr('id', "tweet")
        .attr('class', "twitter-share-button")
        .attr('data-lang', "en")
        .attr('data-count', "none")
        .text('Tweet');
    $("#tweet-span").prepend(tweet);
    tweet.attr('data-text', dynamictext);//add dynamic title if need
    tweet.attr('data-url', dynamicurl);
    twttr.widgets.load();
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you explain your code?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I have updated the code. now we can test how the dynamic url can bind to twitter share button. By default Twitter share button takes browser url as shared, if we want to share some dynamic url (means we can add some parameters to our url) this function use for that.

Comment: In the above code when we click on 'TestTwitter' button twitter share url change to "http://www.google.com".

Comment: Your answer is good and works, but it really hard to understand what do you mean to do at first sight.