# Twitter share button: share hash part of URL?

Tags: javascript, url, twitter, pushstate

I have a site that dynamically updates the URL hash as the user navigates through it (it's a Backbone.js app and I'm using pushState).

I'd like the user to be able to tweet the full URL, including the hash.

I'm using the Twitter share button, but it seems to only share the basic URL path, not the hash, which is quite important:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
```

Any ideas for how I can let users share the hash as well?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are using pushState, so there shouldn't be a hash unless the user uses an old browser.

Comment: Sure, but I need to support users with old browsers...

Comment: I think this may be the best answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215806/how-to-update-the-twitter-share-button-url-with-dynamic-content I hope Twitter add an option to include this by default.

Answer (score 13):

the trick is to replace the hash sign with its html encoded character which is : %23

Comment: For JS, use `encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)`. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Answer (score 0):

Does that button use the referer? If yes, you are out of luck - the hash is [never sent to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039306/send-a-location-hash-through-a-referrer).

However, when using pushState you don't need a hash unless the user's browser is too old - but for everyone with a recent browser it should work fine as the referer will be whatever is currently used in the address bar.